# Is there a way to make cygwin setup remember the -K option

Tags: windows-8, cygwin, setup, digital-signature

I'm using [cygwin](http://cygwin.org/) 64-bit on Windows 8.  I've also gotten some packages from the [Cygwin Ports](http://cygwinports.org/) project.

The instructions on the Cygwin Ports site for running cygwin setup include:

```
cygstart -- /path/to/setup-x86.exe -K http://cygwinports.org/ports.gpg
```

which works.

Is there a way to automatically include that key so I don't have to specify `-K` on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I include that key so I don't have to specify `-K` on the command line?

**Solution 1 - Use a shell script (or alias)**

Add `cygstart -- /path/to/setup-x86.exe -K http://cygwinports.org/ports.gpg` to a shell script or (alias) and run that instead.

**Solution 2 Use a Windows shortcut**

Ceate a shortcut to run the Cygwin Ports setup as follows:

[image]

My target is set to:

```
C:\Downloads\cygwin\setup-x86_64.exe -K http://cygwinports.org/ports.gpg
```

You should adjust "Target" and "Start in" as appropriate for your setup needs.

Comment: A shell script within cygwin could do that too.

Comment: @BrianMinton Yes, or a batch file or a powershell script ... the possibilities are endless. Shell scripts are not so good at running windows programs though. You have to take care with ``\`` and other such oddities for example.

Comment: I always run it from the cygwin command line anyway, which is also how cygwin ports recommends running it.

Comment: @BrianMinton Yes, I just reread the page. Answer updated.